# Kotlin RxJava Nullable Bug

Tags: rx-java, kotlin

I've run into an issue in my Android app using Kotlin and RxJava. It's presented below.

```
import rx.Observable

data class TestUser(val name: String)

fun getTestUser(): Observable<TestUser> {
    return Observable.just(TestUser("Brian")).flatMap { getUser() } // this compiles
}

fun getTestUser2(): Observable<TestUser> {
    val observable = Observable.just(TestUser("Brian")).flatMap { getUser() }
    return observable // this does not compile
}

fun getUser(): Observable<TestUser?> {
    return Observable.just(null)
}
```

In `getTestUser2`, the compiler infers the final return type as `Observable<TestUser?>` and doesn't compile. However in `getTestUser` the code does compile, and when it's run, any subscriber to that observable may be in for a surprise when the `TestUser` comes back `null`.

I'm guessing it's something to do with going back and forth between Kotlin and Java. But, the fact that the compiler *can* see the difference in `getTestUser2` makes me think this could be fixable.

Edit

This is on Kotlin 1.0, the final version released just yesterday (Feb 15, 2016).

Comment: I think, this is the issue tracker they are using: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT . You are much more likely to receive confirmation / explanation from the creators of the language, if you create a bug report

Comment: The team confirmed it is a bug. The issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11108

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The signature of the `flatMap` function is as follows when used in Kotlin:

```
public final fun <R: Any!, T: Any!> 
    Observable<T>.flatMap(
      func: ((T) -> Observable<out R!>!)!
    ) : Observable<R!>!
```

From the docs:

> Any reference in Java may be `null`, which makes Kotlin’s requirements
>   of strict null-safety impractical for objects coming from Java. Types
>   of Java declarations are treated specially in Kotlin and called
>   platform types. Null-checks are relaxed for such types, so that safety
>   guarantees for them are the same as in Java

and

> `T!` means “`T` or `T?`”

This means that the Kotlin compiler can regard the return type of the `flatMap` function as either `Observable<TestUser>` or `Observable<TestUser?>`, or even `Observable<TestUser>?`. The relaxation part says so much as, "we don't want to bother you with these unknown types, you probably know better".

Since the return type is explicitly given in `getTestUser()`, it uses the first. Since the type of `observable` is *not* explicitly given, it infers it to `Observable<TestUser?>`, based on the `getUser()` function.

---

As @voddan commented, there is an open issue discussing this problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11108

Comment: Accepted this. Well researched and presented. That makes sense. I'll probably start being more explicit by assigning the value before returning it like in the 2nd example. I want all the type safety I can get.

Comment: That's weird. Assignment without a type declaration should not change a thing.

Comment: The team confirmed it is a bug. The issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11108

Comment: @voddan interesting!